# Java : Converting colored image to monochrome and keep text readable

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tesseract, tess4j

I am working on a project in which I am planning to use `tesseract OCR` to extract text from given image. When I provide monochrome images, then Tesseract does not have much problem.

Colored images are however a completely different scenario. I get mostly garbled text out of it. So I thought of converting to image to monochrome and then passing it to Tesseract. Unfortunately my efforts of conversion have not yielded any satisfactory results.

The image is getting converted to monochrome, but the text is somehow getting screwed(can't think of an appropriate word). **Even I was unable to read the text properly, how can I expect the program to?**

So the main problem I am facing is, how can I convert a colored image to monochrome in Java where text is not screwed(again).

Our project runs on Linux server, so if there are any scripts or some other programs, which I can call from Java and get result back is also okay. But I would prefer in Java.

Here is the code I have :

```
 @Override
    public void testOcr() {
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        File imageFile = new File("/home/username/other.jpg");
BufferedImage img = null;
            img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

            BufferedImage blackNWhite = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D graphics = blackNWhite.createGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            File outputfile = new File("/home/username/other1.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(blackNWhite, "jpg", outputfile);
   instance.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/");
            // ISO 693-3 standard
            instance.setLanguage("deu");
            String result = instance.doOCR(outputfile);
            System.out.println(result);
}
```

Both images :

[image]

Converted image :

[image]

Here is what I got back from Tesseract for above :

```
90/(/a —’Ä(l/énÄ ' ß(l(1(»m]«u
„„ „‚„„„ „ „„ „„ „‚„„„ „„ n 00 w—v „„„ s 3 na
‘„‘‚';‚ J‘;;Mt:.‘ *‘ “ ‘„*;;131:„'r„‘:1 „ . A „„ „„ _ «3 uu
„„ „.„„„\ „„ „„ uu „„„„\„..\ ; 5 oo “ ‘ " "' ‘* ‘=* —“ "°
„...„.„„. „‘ ‘„‘ „„ „„-„..„‚„„‚» <b(m
„..„„„„.‘ \ „„-„‚„„„„„k („m
„„„\„„„„ muu ‚„„„„„‚ s»’ou
m M 6«»//%
' ‚ , \ ‚“ _ „„ sKUD
:> 3 — „».>' ' z«„„«.„«„„„ <3(m
' ‘)\‚ia "‚ “ l’ ‚„„„.„„\_ „rm
.„.‚\ ‚ . \. .
‘. ‚„.‚.A _ \ „ „ "*°‘Ä‘ „„w„„m„»v.. mm
; ‚ \ :« ‘ 4 ‚ _.
»"9 » @ We have Spema\smr
' Lunch & D\nner ew3rydav
' ßm/n'/ ‚0(*JJP1/'
V\S\\ Cur '<’e3\au\an\ ’
?“"‘:‘“1“1C1„ 55"" ::‘‚:J:'.J‘.‘t‘:‘;1f:.1?t„ ““ Fur6'2a:'z:‘e '
..„„.‘„‚„.„„‘„..„ ‘ s7uu x.„„.„„..„.‘<h„.„„„ ;7uu Eng\gnCp -
5::r‘Ja‘.‘7r“x:1f‘."‘3:l'_„„ ““ ‘°°° @ us ‘
„.„..„‚„ „„„‚„‚ „ uu m.„„„< „„„„ sB 00 \23‚g5f„ 78% .L
—
```

So, any suggestions on how to improvise reading of colored images. Thank you.

Comment: Is the input image given in *this* resolution, and *not* a higher one? Then it will be difficult. (The smaller text is hard to read even in the input image now...)

Comment: @Marco13 : This is just a test image. Width : 700pixels, Height : 542 pixels. Type : JPEG. But even if that is correct, the big text is also not identified as seen from the output.

Comment: I think the approaches that can be used here will also depend on the size of the input image. So how large is this image in the **real** application case? And can you provide/add an image that is as large as the images that you actually want to process?

Comment: @Marco13 : Unfortunately, use-case does not involve specific size images. Best possible translation is what I am looking for. I agree there will be some mistakes for large text and weird font text, but that's acceptable. But basic functionality should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV for binarisation. But; teserract still needs resizing if you want proper result for this example.

This order should work fine.

1. Additional image process operations(denoise, deskew, unsharp, crop, border)
2. Resize image
3. Binarize image
4. OCR

Comment: Why is resizing necessary, I fail to understand that part. Shouldn't Tesseract scan the image pixel by pixel and determine characters in those pixels? Can you tell me any way how I can club tasks 1 and 3 somehow.

Comment: 1) You can use OpenCV `threshold` method for binarisation. **OTSU** threshold can be good choice for binarisation. You can use OpenCV in Java.

2) For this part, there is no certain solution. You need to try different methods and see which methods works for you.

3) Teserract works best if font size is about 12 pt. If texts are smaller than 12 pt, enlarging can improve performance.